# Understanding scipy's least square function with IRLS

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how this function works.

```
a, b = scipy.linalg.lstsq(X, w*signal)[0]
```

I know that signal is the array representing the signal and currently `w` is just `[1,1,1,1,1...]`

How should I manipulate `X` or `w` to imitate weighted least squares or iteratively reweighted least squared?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you product X and y with sqrt(weight) you can calculate weighted least squares.
You can get the formula by following link:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_%28mathematics%29#Weighted_linear_least_squares

here is an example:

Prepare data:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
N = 20
X = np.random.rand(N, 3)
w = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
y = np.dot(X, w) + np.random.rand(N) * 0.1
```

OLS:

```
from scipy import linalg
w1 = linalg.lstsq(X, y)[0]
print w1
```

output:

```
[ 0.98561405  2.0275357   3.05930664]
```

WLS:

```
weights = np.linspace(1, 2, N)
Xw = X * np.sqrt(weights)[:, None]
yw = y * np.sqrt(weights)
print linalg.lstsq(Xw, yw)[0]
```

output:

```
[ 0.98799029  2.02599521  3.0623824 ]
```

Check result by statsmodels:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
mod_wls = sm.WLS(y, X, weights=weights)
res = mod_wls.fit()
print res.params
```

output:

```
[ 0.98799029  2.02599521  3.0623824 ]
```

Comment: Thanks! Why do you use sqrt(weight)? Is it because it will be squared in error compute?

Comment: Is there a simple way to generalize it when X is a matrix?

Answer (score 5):

Create a diagonal matrix `W` from the elementwise square-roots of `w`. Then I think you just want:

```
scipy.linalg.lstsq(np.dot(W, X), np.dot(W*signal))
```

Following http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)#Weighted_linear_least_squares