# python method for solving a Weighted Least Squares with non-diagonal weight matrix

Tags: python, least-squares

I'm using `linalg.lstsq(A,y)` to solve a least squares problem of the type `y=Ax`.

When I want to solve a WLS problem with a diagonal weight matrix W, I can use the solution suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19624997/understanding-scipys-least-square-function-with-irls) and apply:

```
wA = A * np.sqrt(np.diagonal(W))
wy = y * np.sqrt(np.diagonal(W))
linalg.lstsq(wA, wy)[0]
```

However, if `W` is not diagonal this will not work.
I can apply the analytic solution (according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares)) of:

```
ATwA = np.dot(np.dot(A.T,W),A)
ATwy = np.dot(np.dot(A.T,W),y)
linalg.lstsq( ATwA , ATwy  )[0]
```

But I wonder if there is a possibility, using `linalg`, or another library, of just calling something like:

```
solve(y,A,W)
```

Comment: did you look at - http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit.html

Comment: @wwii, the weights there are diagonal.