# How to use least squares with weight matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, least-squares

I know how to solve A.X = B by least squares using Python:

Example:

```
A=[[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1],[1,1,0,0]]
B=[1,1,1,1,1]
X=numpy.linalg.lstsq(A, B)
print X[0]
# [  5.00000000e-01   5.00000000e-01  -1.66533454e-16  -1.11022302e-16]
```

But what about solving this same equation with a weight matrix not being Identity:

```
A.X = B (W)
```

Example:

```
A=[[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1],[1,1,0,0]]
B=[1,1,1,1,1]
W=[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: Have you looked at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19624997/understanding-scipys-least-square-function-with-irls

Comment: Yes; I tried: B=numpy.dot(B,W) before solving, but I have a message: numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: 0-dimensional array given. Array must be two-dimensional

Comment: If you take the dot product of two one-dimensional arrays you will get a scalar. Perhaps you mean to simply multiply the elements of B by those of W? Better to use numpy arrays rather than Python lists here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found another approach (using W as a diagonal matrix, and matricial products) :

```
A=[[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1],[1,1,0,0]]
B = [1,1,1,1,1]
W = [1,2,3,4,5]
W = np.sqrt(np.diag(W))
Aw = np.dot(W,A)
Bw = np.dot(B,W)
X = np.linalg.lstsq(Aw, Bw)
```

Same values and same results.

Comment: the matrix product is more expensive than the element-wise product of @xnx's suggestion

Comment: might be more computationally expensive but this is way more clear to read. +1 for code clarity with linear algebra

Comment: Thanks! Why do you use sqrt(weight)?

Comment: @MonsieurBeilto, that's because in least squares method a sum of square displacements is minimized `(y - y0) ** 2`, therefore if you rescale y by `sqrt(w)`, a factor of `w` will pop up

Comment: I am confused by the differences between this answer and xnx's answer. Why is the effect the same? You multiply the weights only to some entries of `A` while xnx multiplies them to all the entries of `A`, right?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. When multiplying the diagonal `W` with `A`, e.g. the entry at `[0,0]` is multiplied with every entry in the first row of `A` and all the other entries of the same column in `A` have no effect due to the zero-entries in `W`. It's simple matrix multiplication

Answer (score 10):

I don't know how you have defined your weights, but you could try this if appropriate:

```
import numpy as np
A=np.array([[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1],[1,1,0,0]])
B = np.array([1,1,1,1,1])
W = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
Aw = A * np.sqrt(W[:,np.newaxis])
Bw = B * np.sqrt(W)
X = np.linalg.lstsq(Aw, Bw)
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't know well numpy, and have to realize that W[:,np.newaxis] (or W[:,None]) gives a diagonal matrix. I.e. array([[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]]) means a 5x5 diagonal matrix with these values on the diagonal.

Comment: (Is it ? Because the result Aw is a 5x4 array, so that's the only explanation)

Comment: Sorry, I was confused by the * operator (I was not used to arrays). It is not a matrix product, but term to term.

Comment: That's right, NumPy arrays use * as the elementwise multiplication operator. You need to turn W into a column array to broadcast this multiplication correctly over A. There is also a NumPY matrix object, but it's more trouble than it's worth (IMO).

Comment: Thanks! Why do you use sqrt(weight)? Is it because it will be squared in error compute?

Comment: @MonsieurBeilto You can read about this in the Introduction section of the relevant Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_least_squares – if you assume the observational errors are uncorrelated then the weight matrix is diagonal with entries equal to the reciprocal of the measurement variances and the formulas simplify nicely if one refactors using the square root of this matrix.

Answer (score 1):

scikit package offers weighted regression directly ..
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.fit

```
import numpy as np
# generate random data
N = 25
xp = [-5.0, 5.0]
x = np.random.uniform(xp[0],xp[1],(N,1))
e = 2*np.random.randn(N,1)
y = 2*x+e
w = np.ones(N)

# make the 3rd one outlier
y[2] += 30.0
w[2] = 0.0

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
# fit WLS using sample_weights
WLS = LinearRegression()
WLS.fit(x, y, sample_weight=w)

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.plot(x,y, '.')
plt.plot(xp, xp*WLS.coef_[0])
plt.show()
```

[image: weighted regression without outlier]