# Weighted Least Squares in Statsmodels vs. Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, statsmodels, least-squares, patsy

I am trying to replicate the functionality of Statsmodels's [weight least squares (WLS)](http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.WLS.html#statsmodels.regression.linear_model.WLS) function with Numpy's [ordinary least squares (OLS)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) function (i.e. Numpy refers to OLS as just "least squares").

In other words, I want to compute the WLS in Numpy. I used [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27128688/how-to-use-least-squares-with-weight-matrix-in-python) as reference, but **drastically different R² values arise** moving from Statsmodel to Numpy.

Take the following example code that replicates this:

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import pandas as pd

# Test Data
patsy_equation = "y ~ C(x) - 1" # Use minus one to get ride of hidden intercept of "+ 1"
weight = np.array([0.37, 0.37, 0.53, 0.754])
y = np.array([0.23, 0.55, 0.66, 0.88])
x = np.array([3, 3, 3, 3])
d = {"x": x.tolist(), "y": y.tolist()}
data_df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# Weighted Least Squares from Statsmodel API
statsmodel_model = smf.wls(formula=patsy_equation, weights=weight, data=data_df)
statsmodel_r2 = statsmodel_model.fit().rsquared      

# Weighted Least Squares from Numpy API
Aw = x.reshape((-1, 1)) * np.sqrt(weight[:, np.newaxis]) # Multiply two column vectors
Bw = y * np.sqrt(weight)
numpy_model, numpy_resid = np.linalg.lstsq(Aw, Bw, rcond=None)[:2]
numpy_r2 = 1 - numpy_resid / (Bw.size * Bw.var())

print("Statsmodels R²: " + str(statsmodel_r2))
print("Numpy R²: " + str(numpy_r2[0]))
```

After running such code, I get the following results:

```
Statsmodels R²: 2.220446049250313e-16
Numpy R²: 0.475486515775414
```

Clearly something is wrong here! Can anyone point out my flaws here? Am I miss understanding the patsy formula?

Comment: Have you verified that the two methods give the same solution to the weighted least squares problem?  If they don't, then there is no point in checking R².

Comment: All your `x` values are the same!  How do you expect to fit a line to that data?

Comment: On second thought, apparently you want the line to go through the origin.  In that case, a few y values at a single x value gives a well-defined problem.  You could compute the slope by taking the weighted average of those y values, and then dividing by x: `np.average(y, weights=weight)/3` gives `0.21441370223978917`, which agrees with `numpy_model`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser How does computing the slope find the R² value? Did I compute an incorrect `numpy_R²` value? And in addition, you said that you divide by `x`, however, you just divided by the *mode* of vector x (i.e. mode = most recurring number). Can you explain a bit more of your calculations?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Looking at the parameters of the Statsmodels WLS model, I get one parameter of `0.643241...`, whereas I get `0.2144137...` when using Numpy. The models don't agree, so I am guessing I am incorrectly calculating the `numpy_model`?

Comment: *"How does computing the slope find the R² value?"* It doesn't, of course.  I was just amending my previous comment and question about all the x values being the same.  For your question about R², you'll probably need someone more familiar with statsmodels implementation of WLS to give an answer.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Ah okay! I will keep looking into this problem! Thanks anyways!

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I see the problem here. In the `patsy_equation` I have `C(x)`. I am treating my `x` values as categorical and not as numerical variables. If I just put `x` instead of `C(x)`, then I get the same model. Do you have any idea what is happening with the shift from numerical to categorical? More importantly, **how is the math changing?**

Comment: (years later) your `Aw` is just a vector, 4 x 1 ??  Also weights are sometimes ~ sigma, sometimes ~ 1/sigma; try weights all 1.

Comment: @denis If I am remembering correctly, that is actually what it ended up being. I had to use `1/weight` in order for this to start working. Also, as stated in my previous comment too, I was using the wrong patsy_equation. I was treating the values as categorical, when I should have been treating them as continuous, numerical values.