# Get the slope and error of a weighted least square line using scipy curve_fit

Tags: python, scipy, linear-regression, curve-fitting

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def func(x, a, b):
    return a * x + b

x = [0, 1, 2, 3]
y = [160, 317, 3302, 16002]
yerr = [0.0791, 0.0562, 0.0174, 0.0079]

curve_fit(func, x, y, sigma=yerr)
```

I am trying to do a weighed least square linear regression with the code above using scipy's curve_fit function. From this I need to get the slope and the error of the fit. I think I figured out how to get the slope using the below code, but I don't know how to extract the error of the fit.

```
# Code to get the slope (correct me if i'm wrong!!)
popt = curve_fit(func, x, y, sigma=yerr)
slope = popt[0]
```

Thank you!

======================================

Edit: I have been doing some research and I think I might have figured everything out for myself. I will do my best to explain it!

From the image below, I provide this function to curve_fit with **a** and **b** being my parameters corresponding to slope and intercept respectively.

When you use curve fit it returns a 1D array, popt, and a 2D array pcov.
popt contains the optimization of my provided parameters, so in this case, `popt[0]` is slope (green) and `popt[1]` is intercept (red).

Next, the pcov matrix represents covariance. What I'm mainly looking for here are the values on the diagonal, as these correspond to the variance of each parameter. Again I color coded these so that slope error is `pcov[0,0]` (green) and intercept error is `pcov[1,1]` (red).

[image]

From this I was able to get the slope of my line and its error. I hope this explanation can be helpful to someone else!!

Comment: That code would be wrong.`curve_fit`returns `(popt, pcov)` So your `popt[0]` would be `curve_fit`s `popt`

Comment: That said, one needs to point out that you unnecessarily use non-linear optimization for a simple regression.

Comment: So what would a better solution be? I was under the impression that I needed curve_fit so I could include the error in my y values. In truth I don't fully understand this function!

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments:

`curve_fit` is a non linear fit that is definitively not necessary to make a linear regression.

If however used, your code would need to look like:

```py
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y, sigma=yerr)
slope = popt[0]
```

That said, it is better to use the linear approach. One approach is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27150958/803359), with the explanation going like this:

Use `numpy.linalg.lstsq` to minimize `A x = b`, where the math behind is using the minimization of `( A x - b ).T ( A x - b )`
The weighted problem is `( A x - b ).T W ( A x - b )`
With `W` being diagonal we can write it as `W = V.T V` so one has

`( A x - b ).T W ( A x - b ) =`

`= ( A x - b ).T V.T V ( A x - b )`

`= (V A x - V b ).T  (V A x - V b )`

Hence, it is reduced to the original problem with `A`  -> `V A`  and `b` -> `V b`

Note,`W`does not need to be diagonal, but will be real and symmetric and if an inverse exists we will be able to  diagonalize it to `W = Q D Q.T` with `Q` being orthogonal and `D` diagonal.